# Haskell (-1) number issue

Tags: haskell

Imagine this:

```
f = (*10) . (+1)
```

It is a simple way to say to add 1 and then multiply by 10. Now check the following:

```
f = (* 10) . (-1)
```

Here `-1` is a number, not a function, I would like to know if there is a function available to avoid this

```
\x -> x - 1
```

or this

```
flip (-) 1
```

I know they are right, but I would like to not make it be like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtracting numbers can be accomplished via the `subtract` function

`subtract 1` is equivalent to `\x -> x - 1`

So,

`f = (* 10) . subtract 1`

Comment: I've found it on hoogle at the same time you answered! I think I am getting tired :P, this is the exactly right function.

Comment: Fantastic :) Mark it if you want

Comment: I will, I am just waiting the waiting time